# What could cause a lower manifold pressure at full power after an annual?

Tags: aircraft-performance, beechcraft-bonanza

I recently completed the annual on my E33 Bonanza.  I notice on takeoff at full power that the MAP is about 1" less pressure than it was in the past at my home airport.  It is also about 1.5" less than ambient.  I notice less power slower Acceleration and lower climb rates.  Fuel flow looks normal.  Where else should I search and troubleshoot?

Comment: Are the actual airport and your home airport at the same elevation?

Comment: Due to the resistance of the air filter the MP should be about an inch less than ambient so what you are seeing seems about right.  If there was a leak in the intake manifold before the air filter (before the annual) then that might explain why your engine developed more power before (although the engine sucked in dirt).